# Find a class in a jQuery object and append HTML ul to it

Tags: jquery

In the above javascript object, I want to be able to find the class .inject and append a ul, li to it. How can it be achieved?

```
var $variable = $('<h5>'+ opts.fields.ac_firstname +' '+ opts.fields.ac_lastname+ ' ('+opts.fields.ac_source_id +')</h5><div class="inject"><append ul li here></div><p style="font-weight:bold; margin:1em 0 0;">View Summary</p><div class="bcCallToAction"><a href="" target="_blank">Visit google.com</a></div>');
```

---

Tried this but dint work

```
  if(opts.fields.ac_othernames.length > 1){               
                        $.each(opts.fields.ac_othernames, function(k, v){
                             altNameMarkup += '<li>' + v + '</li>';
                        });
                        var $ulAltNms = $('<ul>');
                        $ulAltNms.append(altNameMarkup);
                        $variable.find('.inject').append($ulAltNms);

                    }
```

Comment: What about `$variable.find('.inject').append($ulAltNms);` ?

Comment: You seem to be looking for the class `.altNames` and not `.inject`. Is that a mistake or deliberate?

Comment: was a mistake, corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find` gets descendants of the elements in the current collection, filtered by a selector expression. That won't work, since your desired element is at the root of the collection. Instead, use `filter` to retrieve it:

```
$injectElement = $variable.filter('.inject'); //do something with this
```

Also, please stop fiddling with raw markup when the DOM interfaces of the elements are accessible to you. You can add a list to the element using:

```
$ul = $('<ul />');

$.each(opts.fields.ac_othernames, function(k, v){
     $ul.append($('<li />').html(v));
});

$injectElement.append($ul);
```